# Merging column in a datatable

Tags: php, html-table, datatables

I'm trying to create datatable in order to make use of the export options. I understand that the table won't work if tags are incorrect. I'm trying to achieve a table that will list a recipe ingredients, its quantity and method. As I only want the method to display once, I would like to merge the last column and place it in the center - this is where the problem occurs. I've created an if statement to check that if the method has already been printed. Everything displays the way I would like with the following code but I don't understand how to close the td tag correctly....

The error I receive is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

```
<table id="table_id" class="display" width="50">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th>
            Ingredient
        </th>
        <th>
            Method
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$ifExists = false;
while ($dbRow2 = $dbQuery3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ingredients=$dbRow2["ingredient"];
    $quantity=$dbRow2["quantity"];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo "$quantity";
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo "$ingredients";
    echo '</td>';
    $count=$dbQuery3->rowCount();

    if($ifExists == false){
        echo "<td rowspan='$count'>";
        echo "$method";
        echo '</td>';
        $ifExists = true;
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    else {
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother mistake is simple 
think if your `else` part is executed then it will try to close `</td>` which is not opened

try this

```
else {
//  echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';   
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, still receiving the same error. Previously I had echo '<td></td>'; which solved the error but didn't merge the column

Answer (score 0):

I don't think DataTables currently support the implementation of rowspans inside of the table body (only in the header). There are however some plugins that can be used to group cells together to act as a rowspan - try the rowsGroup plugin (https://github.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup).

Using this plugin inside of your DataTable call you could do something like:

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({'rowsGroup': [2]});
```

Let me know how you get on!